# recyclerview залезает под toolbar

Tags: android, kotlin, recyclerview

значит это сам фрагмент с recyclerview
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layoutDescription="@xml/fragment_notes_scene2"
    tools:context=".ui.notes.NotesFragment">

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/notebutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="114dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="addnote"
        android:src="@drawable/free_icon_sticky_note_3934366"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/listbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="180dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="addlist"
        android:src="@drawable/free_icon_wishlist_4947789"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerviewitem"
        android:layout_width="412dp"
        android:layout_height="663dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:verticalScrollbarPosition="defaultPosition"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        tools:listitem="@layout/recyclerviewitem"></androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/archivenotesbutton0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="180dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/free_icon_archive_343910"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/deletenotesbutton0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="114dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/newnotebutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
        tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck,ImageContrastCheck" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

это app_bar_menu xml MainActivity
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constraint"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.001">


        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include
        layout="@layout/content_main"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.333"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appBarLayout" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

это content_min который вставляется через include в  app_bar_main
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_content_main"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="406dp"
        android:layout_height="719dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appBarLayout"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation"
        tools:ignore="UnknownIdInLayout" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

при выводе такая картина
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но если опустить фрагмент с recyclerview то будет так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: прикольные картинки) мне нравится) мож код прикрепите?) а то тут пока помочь вряд ли кто сможет

Comment: готово, сделал.

Comment: я бы предложил начать с того что убрать фиксированные размеры контейнеров, у вас  у фрагмента очень фиксированная высота/ширина, поставьте match_parent/wrap_content и то же самое у списка, они должны нормально вставать при своих нефиксированных размерах

Comment: я не могу, иначе ресайклвью залезает под тулбар